# What are the options when implementing authentication on Next 13?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, authentication, next.js, jwt

I'm building a project using Next as a monolith, it sounds very strange but I had this idea of building all of the business logic with API Routes and server components. Given that, i having the following question? what are the option when we talk about authentication/authorization?

currently, I have a login API route that receives a email and a password and returns a JWT token in the response body, then my frontend, or more precisely: client side login component,  takes the response and saves a cookie containing the token. this cookie is set to expire in 1 hour. after the cookie is saved, my login component redirects the user to a profile page, using the router from useRouter().

```
export default function LoginForm() {

    const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm<InputFields>();
    const { push } = useRouter();

    const [loginError, setLoginError] = useState<ApiError>({});


    const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<InputFields> = ({ email, password }) => {
        signIn({ email, password })
            .then(() => {
                push("/profile");
            })
            .catch(error => {
                setLoginError(error);
            })
    }
...
```

The `/profile` route is a private route, in my app, private routes and public routes are rendered  separately through a client component called RouteSeparator that checks if the route is private or public before rendering it

```
export default function RouteSeparator({ children }: RouteSeparatorProps) {
    
    const pathname = usePathname();
    const isPublicPage = checkIfPublicRoute(pathname);

    return <>
        {isPublicPage && children}
        {!isPublicPage && (
            <PrivateRoute>
                {children}
            </PrivateRoute>
        )}
    </>
}
```

Since the `/profile` route is private, it is rendered inside this other component called PrivateRoute. This component only responsibility is check if the cookie set before exists and is valid. then it takes the data of the cookie(user name, email and other useful user data) and pass it to a context in the client. My question is: Is this the most efficient/secure approach? is there a way to make this entire validation within the server side?

Comment: You would just read / decode the cookie jwt in layout.js, right?